Jetpack compose how to scroll whole screen with lazycolumn
I have a title "Cars" at the top and a loading spinner that takes up the center of the remaining space below the title. The loading spinner is only visible if isLoading is true. If isLoading is false the carsList is displayed below the title "Cars" and takes up the remaining space below the title.
Currently with the code below, only the items in the LazyColumn scroll. But I want the whole screen to scroll, how do I achieve this?
If I use regular XML code, I can achieve this by having NestedScrollView as the parent and a RecyclerView as a child and set android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false".
@Composable
fun CarScreen(
    isLoading: Boolean,
    carsList: List<Car>
) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 32.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Cars",
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )

        if (isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            )
        }

        if (!isLoading) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            ) {
                item {
                    Text(
                        text = "List of SUVs",
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp)
                    )
                }
                items(carsList) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                            .background(Color.Gray)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Brand: ${it.brand}")
                        Text(text = "Model: ${it.model}")
                        Text(text = "Model: ${it.year}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Image when isLoading true
Image when isLoading false
I tried two things so far:

I tried setting LazyColumn(userScrollEnabled = false) but this completely disabled the scrolling which is not what I want. I want the whole screen to scroll instead of the LazyColumn scrolling alone.

I tried converting the top most parent Column into a LazyColumn and wrapped every individual composable inside it with item or items. But I noticed many modifier functions were not available inside the item and items block. Also this way didn't seem elegant and required a lot of extra code, surely jetpack compose provides a simple way?



Do you want to show header while loading or not?

@SanthoshKumar the header should be visible while loading

You can put the title inside the LazyColumn using the item {} block to make it scroll and put the LazyColumn in a Box to make the progress indicator appear in the center:

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            item { Text("Cars") }
            if (!isLoading) {
                items(cars) { car -> 
                    // ... your car elements here
                }
            }
        }
        if (isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }



The progress indicator should be centered inside the remaining height below the title. But in your solution the progress indicator is centered with respect to the entire screen.
